# Why Type Traits is not working inside namespace (std::enable_if) - c++11

Tags: c++, c++11

**If the following code is placed inside a namespace then its not working, but without namespace its working fine...**

```
template <typename T,typename _F>
inline typename std::enable_if< is_iterable<T>::value >::type
for_all_ele(T&& arr,_F&& fn)
{
    for(auto &x:arr)
        for_all_ele(x,fn);

}

template <typename T,typename _F>
inline typename std::enable_if< not is_iterable<T>::value >::type
for_all_ele(T&& x,_F&& fn)
{
    fn(x);
}
```

is_iterable is defined over it...

The full code is here : http://ideone.com/goJ0Zf

Till now all I can find is the template specialization of 'for_all_ele'  for scalar data is not being detected inside namespace...

Comment: Please fold in a [MCVE] into your question, even if one is in the link.  That means taking the code in the link and stripping out the parts that don't matter.  Note that the code *above* works (in that it does nothing) both inside and outside a namespace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursion works when it is found via Koenig Lookup (aka ADL, aka Argument Dependent Lookup) and not when it is not found that way.

This call:

```
{
  for(auto &x:arr)
    for_all_ele(x,fn);
}
```

does not see the later declared `for_all_ele`, *unless* one of `x` or `fn` finds it via ADL.  As it happens, when it isn't in a namespace, the lambda you pass as `fn` is in the same (root) namespace as your `for_all_ele` function is.  So it is found.

When `for_all_ele` is in a namespace, it doesn't work, because the lambda is in a different namespace.

There are three approaches.

First, you can forward-declare it.

Second, you can create a wrapping function.  It then instantiates a toy type (`struct toy_tag{};`) and passes it together with the other arguments to the `for_all_ele_impl`, which pass said `toy_tag` when they recurse.

Third, you can simply move the recursive case after the terminating case: https://ideone.com/17h75Q

```
template <class T, class F>
inline typename std::enable_if< is_iterable<T>::value >::type
for_all_ele(T&& arr,F&& f)
{
  for(auto&&x:arr)
    for_all_ele(decltype(x)(x),f);
}

template <class T, class F>
inline typename std::enable_if<
  !is_iterable<T>::value
>::type
for_all_ele(T&& t,F&& f) {
  std::forward<F>(f)(std::forward<T>(t));
}
```

I renamed your `_F` to `F`, as the name `_F` is reserved by the standard in all contexts.  I also perfect forwarded the function object, because I'm like that.  And I did some perfect forwarding your code was missing.

Comment: `not` :) `T and x, F and fn` :P

Comment: @T.C. inherited from OP.  But ya, just edited to be made more conventional.

Comment: Well Thanks for ur approaches,
The 3rd one worked very well for me, I'm not sure about the second approach but I CAN'T IMPLEMENT THE forward declaration approach, it gives me same error just like before...
Here is my trial...
[http://ideone.com/x39cMV](http://ideone.com/x39cMV)